# Animate div container no stay in same position

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have div container with image as background of jet , i want simulate jet flight of this element , the moving go from right to the left when animate this element i get move from position left : 600 px to position left:-1600 px , but no works for repit this other time , return position 600 px left and other time go to -1600 px

**I put my code here :**

```
 $("#header_fly_1").fadeIn(100, function() {

        $(this).animate({
            'left': '-1600'
        }, 8000);
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        $("#header_fly_1").css('right','0').fadeIn(100, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                'left': '-1600'
            }, 8000);
        });
    }, 5000);
```

I try many times but no get works as one animation loop

Regards !

Comment: Any fiddle to play with?

Comment: Yes here : http://jsfiddle.net/haEJb/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are setting right and left, check if this works:

```
$(function() {
    $("#header_fly_1").fadeIn(100, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'right': '50%'
        }, 1500);
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        $("#header_fly_1").css('right','0').hide().fadeIn(100, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                'right': '50%'
            }, 1500);
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

#### Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/haEJb/2/)

Comment: Think in jet start in the right in one position and go to other postion to the left and when end in the left position start other time the animation in the same position and go to the left

Comment: px doesn't work because I am using a monitor of `1024 x 768` others might have `1280 x 960`. Got it?